# Rails .where using between vs greater/less than

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to speed up one of my queries in my rails app.

Right now I'm using
`.where(['num_units >= ? and num_units <= ?',min_units,max_units])`

Would it be faster or more beneficial to change it to 
`.where(num_units: min_units..max_units)`?

This is in Rails 4 by the way.

**Edit:**
I realized that I will most likely need to index the column for what I need, which speeds this query a lot. And one of my co-workers informed me that they are pretty much identical

Comment: Even after your update, it still seems as though @Mtarantini answered your question. Not sure what else you are looking for here since you believe all you needed was an index on num_units anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check queries to see which one is fastest by testing them this way:

```
Benchmark.measure do
  100000.times do
    # Change 'Class' to your class name.
    Class.where('num_units >= ? and num_units <= ?', min_units, max_units)
  end
end

Benchmark.measure do
  100000.times do
    Class.where('num_units BETWEEN ? AND ?', min_units, max_units)
  end
end

Benchmark.measure do
  100000.times do
    Class.where(num_units: min_units..max_units)
  end
end
```

The times that I got back in my local testing, following the order above:

1. @real=3.280792
2. @real=3.312653
3. @real=3.709074

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but one of my co-workers told me they are essentially the same. What I really needed was an index on num_units.

Comment: Correct. That's what the benchmarking shows. The speed difference is not dramatic.